# Doxygen, nothing shows up in Graphical Class Hierarchy

Tags: c++, windows, doxygen

I'm trying to use DOxygen to generate documentation for a rather large code base.

I got Doxygen 1.8.10 for Windows with Doxywizard.

I installed Graphviz 2.38

I was able to generate the Textual Class Hierarchy without a problem using Recursive option in the Expert tab.

I selected the "Use dot tool from GraphViz package" option in the Wizard.

I also checked "HAVE_DOT" and "CLASS_DIAGRAMS" options in the Expert tab for Dot.

When I generate the documentation and click on Show HTML Output, I cannot see anything under the Graphical Class Hierarchy. I can still see all the classes and their dependencies in the Textual Class Hierarchy.

in Mozilla Firefox, the Graphical Class Hierarchy page shows up as empty
in Internet Explorer, the Graphical Class Hierarchy page shows a lot of broken image icons aligned in 1 column

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you,

Comment: Check that Graphviz is correctly installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you select `HAVE_DOT` in the Expert Tab, doxygen will assume you have DOT available from the PATH. You need to make sure of this.

However, you also have the `DOT_PATH` option. Here you can put the path where DOT can be found.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve this issue by executing a simple line on CMD which iteratively generates the missing .png files from .dot files.

```
for %f in (*dot) do dot %~nxf -Tpng -o %~nf.png
```

Make sure to execute this in */html* folder where all .dot files reside and have dot.exe in your PATH environment variable. Also, If you receive any syntax errors, such as:

> syntax error in line 1 near 'ëPNG'

try changing the default program of .dot format to Notepad (mine was set to Word).

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? Which problem did you encounter? The mentioned "solution" cannot be the intention as soxygen does automatic translation of the `.dot` files provided you have `dot` installed (and have `dot` in your path or otherwise have `DOT_PATH=...` set correctly. Also to be able to "post-generate" the png files you have to have the `DOT_CLEANUP=NO`. Best is to show the contents of your doxygen configuration file (insofar as it is different from the default configuration file, for doxygen > 1.8.16: `doxygen -x`) as well as the error messages you get.